# nil check inside getter method in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, properties

I have an array in my view controller. It should be allocated only if it is nil otherwise it should return the existing value.

**Objective C equivalent:**

```
- (NSArray*)states{
     if(!_states)
     {
         _states = //read files from json and assigned to array
     }
     return _states;
}
```

I have to achieve this in swift. I tried with stored property but not able to achieve this

what is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be something like that:

```
class Whatever {
    private(set) var _states: [AnyObject]?
    var states: [AnyObject] {
        get{
            if let st = _states {
                return st
            }
            else {
                // Read from file
                _states = ....
                return _states!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In SWIFT there is no concept of instance variable, but just properties, by writing this `private(set) var _states: [AnyObject]?` we are saying that _states can't be written from outside our class, but just inside. Then we create a readonly property which duty is read our `_states` bind it to `st` if it is not nil or fill it with data.
There is a more SWIFTY way to do that called lazy properties:

```
class Whatever {
    lazy var states: [AnyObject] = {
        return array read from file
    }()
}
```

By using lazy, we are saying to create that array only at the first call to the property, once is set it will never be created again, but just returned. Basically it will not pass again to the array creation from the file.

Comment: I would like to use lazy property. For example, States are loaded but after some stage I need to load the array again since the file got updated. In objective C, I will just set nil for my states property then it will load the new set of values from file. In the same way can i follow here in lazy property?

Comment: No, once created you can't nil a lazy property, you must stay stick at the first option

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

we can use like this also, in Swift 3.0.

```
private var _designContentViewController: DesignContentViewController?

var designContentViewController: DesignContentViewController? {
    get {
        if _designContentViewController == nil {
            _designContentViewController = DesignContentViewController()
            self.view.addSubview((_designContentViewController?.view)!)
            _designContentViewController?.view.isHidden = true
            _designContentViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
        return _designContentViewController

    }
    set {
        _designContentViewController = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You go in two steps. You use a stored property like _states which contains an optional array. Then you have a computed property states which accesses the _states optional array and either returns the unwrapped value or loads _states first.